# How do I set Emacs tab size to 4 chars wide for .py files?

Tags: emacs

I've tried using the following:

```
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq-default tab-stop-list (list 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60))
```

But the size of tabs when editing .py files is still 8 chars wide. In other files it has gone down to 4, so I assume the Python major mode is overriding this somehow. I see that I can set python-indent to 4, but this causes spaces to be inserted (which goes against our code style guide).

How do I make the tabs 4 chars in width?

#### Update:

I've also tried this, but it didn't do anything:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
  (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
  (setq tab-width 4)
)
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
        (setq tab-width 4)
        (setq python-indent-offset 4)))
```

Comment: tab is the endless headache. I suggest to use: "(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)"

Comment: Agreed: when you use tabs, you are entering a world of pain.

Comment: @HongboZhu Does not work very well in CHANGELOG or Make files.

Comment: `python indent` is obsolete since 24.3. Use `python-indent-offset` instead.

Comment: Emacs is a world of pain with tabs. For reasons that are beyond comprehension. Whey can't emacs allow proper tab usage for indentation and automatically use spaces for alignment?

Comment: @ceving: emacs is smart enough to locally enable `indent-tabs-mode`  in Makefile or ChangeLog buffers.

Answer (score 2):

The correct form for the hook is this:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
            (setq tab-width 4)))
```

You need to put the imperative statements inside a function (lambda).

Comment: This solves my original problem, but introduces a new problem; now it tabs twice where it should only tab once. However, pt has provided the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
(setq indent-tabs-mode t)
(setq python-indent-offset 4)
```

Comment: Didn't help, sorry. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that same issue, but with C++ files. What finally did it for me was the following in my `.emacs`.

```
(custom-set-variables
;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
'(c-basic-offset 4 t)
)
```

Actually of course I set it from the C++ mode area of the `Customize Emacs` menu, but this was the result. I'd see if python mode has something similar. `py-basic-offset` or something? Surf around the mode settings for pyton.

Comment: `py-basic-offset` does not exist.